# Streaming RTSP feed over DLNA

Tags: media-server, ffmpeg, rtsp

I have a 'smart' TV that has a very limited set of functions, one of them being it can stream videos from any DLNA server on the LAN.

I have an RTSP stream on the network that I would like to view on the TV.

I tried installing `minidlna` on the Pi and dumping the RTSP stream to a FIFO in the media folder using ffmpeg

```
mkfifo video.mp4
ffmpeg -i 'rtsp://link-to-rtsp-feed' -acodec copy -vcodec copy video.mp4
```

but `minidlna` doesn't seem to detect the file as a valid video file - it doesn't come up in the library.

Can I convince `minidlna` to stream the file? Can I transcode it to a different format? Or is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 0):

Using that command ffmpeg will simply overwrite video.mp4 with a regular file. What you need instead is:

```
ffmpeg -i 'rtsp://link-to-rtsp-feed' -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f mp4 - > video.mp4
```

I have not tried this myself however.